# escaping single quotes in a CSV

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4

I'm trying to do a really basic output of data to a CSV file

I have some code like:

```
 <?php echo $csv->getComments() ?>,
```

and

```
<?php echo "comments"."," ?>
```

This outputs the foloowing in a CSv file:

comments,
i like cheese

The problem I'm having is when I'm outputting single quoutes in the comments, such as `i'm loving cheese`

This outputs `,i&#039;m loving cheese` and it breaks my CSV file.

Is there a way to either replace the single quote that has been encoded or just to remove the single quote?

I have seen that I can use an escaping_method in the settings.yml, but using any of the options doesn't seem to affect the output.

Thanks

Comment: Ok, so I turned `escaping_method` off (false). This seems to have fixed my problems.

Comment: You can also use html_entity_decode() and still use Symfony escaping that is usefull to write valid HTML

Comment: Just make `<?php echo $csv->getComments(ESC_RAW) ?>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be symfony's output escaper. All objects passed to a partial are automatically wrapped in an escape output escaper object. There are two ways to get the raw value of your comment:

1. In a partial every method called on an output escaper object accepts a "magic" last parameter, defining the escape method to use. So in your case you can use:

   `echo $csv->getComments(ESC_RAW);`
2. You can free your $csv object from the output escaper by calling the decorators `getRawValue()` method in the first lines of your partial:

   `$csv = $csv->getRawValue();`

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your value with "value"